# No sound in laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio

My windows 7 laptop has no sound. What can I do to get the audio working?

Comment: What is the make and model of your laptop?

Answer (score 0):

go to the manufacturer's web site. locate the support section of the webpage that offers downloads for drivers. select your model of computer. download the driver. install. hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Sound Settings in the Control Panel? Maybe the Sound is muted.
If not then you can download the newest Sound Driver for your laptop as **TurtleToes** mentioned above.